# How to build gitk?

Tags: build, tcl, gitk

How to build gitk on Windows 10? I have installed IronTcl so I can run my local modifications to gitk interpreted but I would like to make it a standalone executable. Other than this single-file script I'm not familiar with tcl at all and I seem to be unable to find any build instructions. I hope you can do it without buying any commercial products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to create self-contained single-file Tcl/Tk applications.  One I have used successfully is http://www.ch-werner.de/cgi-bin/luck.pl

Comment: Thank you for the link. I created a package using the vanillatclsh-win64.exe option but when I try to run the generated exe file I get an error message saying "package require Tk". Googling gave some directions to installing "ActiveTcl" but since that is not needed when running the distributed gitk.exe, I started doubting if I'm on the right track. Can you advice please?

Comment: You need to start with vanillawish, the tclsh option doesn't include Tk.
Using undroidwish also gives you the option to bundle in various Tcl extensions, but you probably don't need that.